# Pure-ftpd как сменить порт?

Tags: vps

Здравствуйте!

Стоит ПУ ajenti (пришлось поставить, т.к. не выходит у меня почему-то общаться с фтп серваками напрямую...)
Так как живу на деде, порезаном на вдски, то порт выделен под фтп 5121, как перекинуть pure-ftpd на данный порт?

etc/pure-ftpd.conf - none

etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ - отсутствует нужное

**Обновление**

Дописал:

[image]

Тут все нормально пишет, а фтп не работает все равно.

Comment: > отсутствует нужное

так допишите

Comment: Обновил вопрос.